# How to fetch particular field value from table in cakephp?

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I want to fetch a single field value from table so that i can compare that boolean value and check the conditions. How to fetch that particular field from table in cakephp?

Comment: Why can't you use the find() method?

Comment: Because the OP is asking how to retrieve a single field value. CakePHP can do this elegantly with the field method.

Comment: In case you're curious as to why your question has been down-voted, it's likely due to the fact that your question is something that is very-specifically explained in the documentation.  Which is what you'll see when hovering over the down arrow: "This question does not show any research effort;".  Not a big deal and nothing to worry about.  Just something to keep in mind for future questions.

Comment: Nobody thinks that he/she wastes their time on research the thing. As he/she should try to solve the problem and problem remains same then they will do expanse time on researching.. I think you people won't understand....:(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, you can get a particular field based on a condition, Use [field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-field) method of model.

```
$this->YourModel->field('field', $yourconditionsarray);
```

For example:

```
 $this->Post->field('name', array('id' => 20));
```

The above gives the name of post of id 20.